# My application freeze when use router.navigate

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular13

I try to return to the main page with

```
navigateToHome () {
    this.router.navigate([''])
    .then(() => {
        window.location.reload();
    });
}
```

html

```
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="container container__screen">
    <div class="container__grow">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-sm button__home" (click)="navigateToHome()">
        <i class="far fa-home"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
...
```

But when loading the main page, everything looks correct (ngOninit load all data ok). It has loaded the data well, but chrome is frozen, I try to press the buttons but it cannot be done.

```
nodejs v16.5.0

"@angular-devkit/core": "13.3.10",
"@angular/animations": "13.3.12",
"@angular/common": "13.3.12",
"@angular/compiler": "13.3.12",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "13.3.12",
"@angular/core": "^13.3.12",
"@angular/forms": "13.3.12",
"@angular/platform-browser": "13.3.12",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.3.12",
"@angular/router": "13.3.12",
```

I tried `this.router.navigate(['/control-guides']);` but does not work

Comment: Avoid using `window.location.reload();` inside `.then()` because this can lead to various problems in Angular. If you want to go back to a route you might should move the code into a service or move code to ` ngOnInit` . 

Otherwise I can't tell you much, I need way more information. Could you provide more code and more information? Since you are new on StackOverflow you can check out: [How To: Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) by StackOverflow to find out how questions in StackOverflow should be written and what components are important.

Comment: thnks for the advice.